# React public/private page architecture menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an app with some public page and some private page with different menu
I use react-router to display all my page with a menu

```
render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <div className="App">
           <MenuPublic />
           <MenuPrivate />

           <Route to='/private' components={Private} />
           <Route to='/private/account' components={PrivateAccount} />

           <Route to='/public' components={Public} />
           <Route to='/public/contact' components={PublicContact} />
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
```

But i have two differents  (Menu public, menu private), one for public and one for private page
I search a good architecture to display my different menu between all my public and my private page

Do you have any solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on what make the user as allowed to see private section (IE: Role)

you can:

```
{this.user.role === 'Admin' && <Route to='/private' components={Private} /> }
```

or:

```
<Route to='/private' components={this.user.role === 'Admin' ? PrivateComponent : NotAllowedComponent } /> }
```

Comment: It's only for the <Menu /> component

Answer (score 0):

You can create HOC for authorization.

i.e.

```
<Route to='/public' components={Public} />
<Route
      to="/private"
      component={Authorization([
        'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN',
        'ROLE_ADMIN',
      ])(Private)}
    />
```

and Authorization component looks like that:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { object } from 'prop-types';

export default function Authorization(allowedRoles) {
  return WrappedComponent => {
    class WithAuthorization extends React.Component {
      static propTypes = {
        user: object.isRequired,
      };

      render() {
        const { user } = this.props;
        if (
          user &&
          user.roles &&
          allowedRoles.some(r => user.roles.includes(r))
        ) {
          return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
        }
        return <h1>This page is forbidden</h1>;
      }
    }
    return connect(state => ({ user: state.session.sessionService.user }))(
      WithAuthorization,
    );
  };
}
```

Comment: It's only for the <Menu /> component